# Model binding with inheritance in Asp.Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to accept list of objects from user:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateArticle(List<InformationBlockModel> informationBlocks)
    {
        ...
    }
```

ModelBinder should determine concrete types, but when I trying to cast InformationBlock to TextInformationBlock, exception throws.

Hierarchy:

```
public class InformationBlockModel
{
    public virtual InformationBlockType Type { get; set; }
}

public class TextInformationBlockModel : InformationBlockModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override InformationBlockType Type { get; set; } = InformationBlockType.Text;
}

public class ImageInformationBlockModel : InformationBlockModel
{
    public override InformationBlockType Type { get; set; } = InformationBlockType.Image;
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *ModelBinder should determine concrete types,* - model binder has no idea which derived types `InformationBlockModel` has and won't ever try to bind parameters into that derived class objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new InformationBlockConverter()));
```

**JsonCreationConverter.cs**

```
public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get; } = false;

    public override bool CanRead { get; } = true;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }

    protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var target = Create(objectType, jObject);

        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }
}
```

**InformationBlockConverter**

```
public class InformationBlockConverter : JsonCreationConverter<InformationBlockModel>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<InformationBlockType, Type> _types = new Dictionary<InformationBlockType, Type>
    {
        {InformationBlockType.Text, typeof(TextInformationBlockModel)},
        {InformationBlockType.Image, typeof(ImageInformationBlockModel)},
        {InformationBlockType.Video, typeof(VideoInformationBlockModel)}
    };

    protected override InformationBlockModel Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        return (InformationBlockModel) jObject.ToObject(_types[Enum.Parse<InformationBlockType>(
            jObject.GetValue("type", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).Value<string>(), true)]);
    }
}
```

**InformationBlockType**

```
public enum InformationBlockType
{
    Text,
    Image,
    Video
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I did have a problem with duplicates showing up in a list, to prevent this, the `Create` override should return a new, empty instance of whatever type is to be returned, rather than converting the `jObject` to the desired type.

Comment: @Eraph, can we just skip `serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);` step instead of creating a new instance of the class? `jObject.ToObject` does the same thing, doesn't it?

Comment: I added the converter, but my api still returns an 'Input is invalid' result. It seems that it still accept only the base class. Does this converter change the signature of expected input? Or do I need something else, like a model binder, for it.

Answer (score 2):

Asp.Net binding does **not** work like this by default.  If you want to this sort of behaviour you will have to write your own [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding), which isn't too difficult.

Or, use a view model:

```
public class InformationBlockViewModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then handle the block type in the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateArticle(List<InformationBlockViewModel> informationBlocks)
{
    foreach (var block in informationBlocks) {        
        switch (block.Type)
        {
            case "Text":
                // Handle text
                break;
            case "Image":
                // Handle image
                break;
            case default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown information block type.");
        }
    }
}
```